# My C IDE does'nt prompt for user input in a loop

Tags: c, loops, ide, cygwin, codeblocks

the code below is to create a challenge that prompts for user input between several 0 - 20. The main purpose is for the user to guess a number that is created by the random number generator, and he/she has to guess it within five tries. However, after compiling and running my code in the code blocks ide, it only prompted the user once before printing out the condition five times and exiting the loop. (So for instance, if the user input is less than the randomNumber, it will go on to print "Your number is wrong, is less than" five times when it should prompt the user after the first failed try.)

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with my code? Or is it the IDE's problem? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    int randomNumber = rand()% 21;
    int number_one;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {

        printf(" Give me a number ");
        scanf("%d", &number_one);

        if (number_one == randomNumber)
        {
            printf("Congratulations you won\n");
            break;
        }

        else if (number_one < randomNumber)
        {
            print("Your number is wrong, is lesser than \n");
        }

        else
        {
            print(" Your number is wrong, is more than\n");
        }

    }

    printf("your 5 tries is up, the number is %d", randomNumber);

}
```

Comment: What is your **exact** input?

Comment: `print` --> `printf` ?

Comment: `break;` --> `return 0;`

Comment: `scanf("%d", &number_one);` --> `if (scanf("%d", &number_one) != 1) {puts"illegal input"); exit(1);}`

Comment: After changing `print` to `printf`, the program works (although you should check the return value from `scanf`) but it's letting the user enter 6 numbers (`for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)`.

Comment: `i <= 5;` --> `i < 5;`

Comment: `exit(1)` (or `return 1` as equally valid alternative) is very basic error handling. If you want to allow re-entering, the input handling might look like this: `while(scanf("%d", &number_one) != 1) { puts("invalid input"); char c; do { c = getchar(); } while(!isspace(c)); }` – note that after a failed `scanf` the invalid input remains in the buffer and must be cleared first
before you can read from `stdin` again.

Comment: Also, check if `scanf` returns `EOF` - If you get `EOF` you should terminate instead.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem lies in First `if` block Statement Block. `break;` statement ends the `for` loop.

The `continue` statement skips the current iteration of the loop and continues with the next iteration. So please use `continue;` instead of `break`.

Also, please change `print` to `printf` in the last two occurrences.

The final code will be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int randomNumber = rand()% 21;
    int number_one;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        printf(" Number is %d \n", randomNumber);
        printf(" Give me a number ");
        scanf("%d", &number_one);

        if (number_one == randomNumber)
        {
            printf("Congratulations you won\n");
            break;
        }

        else if (number_one < randomNumber)
        {
            printf("Your number is wrong, is lesser than \n");
        }

        else
        {
            printf(" Your number is wrong, is more than\n");
        }

    }

    printf("your 5 tries is up, the number is %d", randomNumber);
}
```

Comment: as additional suggestion, the random generator should  be initialized to avoid the same value to be extracted every time https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm